# does signalr work with IE 9?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a web site MVC4c#. I installed signalr 1.0.1
It works great on firefox. but on IE9 cannot connect 
my code :

```
var myHub= $.connection.myHub;
    $.connection.hub.error(function () {
        alert("error connect");
    });

 $.connection.hub.start(function () {
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error connect");
    }).done(function () {
        alert("connect");
    });
```

with firefox it's working . IE 9 no. it used to work with the previous version of SignalR .
sinse I installed package fron nuget 1.0.1 it stoped working on IE.

in IE developers tools I don't see javascript error, in network capture I see:
every 10 seconds it does 2 request: Key Value Request   GET

```
localhost:51090/signalr/ping?_=1363305928522
```

HTTP/1.1 response {"Response":"pong"} and Immediately another request :

```
http://localhost:51090/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=pKuceZE_v-uecAzzq4rgj4Gz6AY1KagOgnzwqtG197hftvZOfK_LDqMo9VI5iRnkX4f2K9Wno7tBzVTxrLi4Xs7doGsChAkL6ejRykvTtDMHMdNR-FlScXPT4wwNeD7Y-AZa1Rb5XVpDUsv2S2qXs3ZSWjxJg9uGiq1QYLG1FUfMVMVDQq8aoDWLjkUGk2CR0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22tradehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C2%7CL%2C2%7CM%2C0%7CN%2C0&tid=3&_=1363305928541
```

with no response

Comment: Did you check in Developer Tools in IE to see if there are any javascript errors?

Comment: every 10 seconds it does 2 request:
Key Value
Request GET http://localhost:51090/signalr/ping?_=1363305928522 HTTP/1.1 
response {"Response":"pong"}

and Immediately another request :
http://localhost:51090/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=pKuceZE_v-uecAzzq4rgj4Gz6AY1KagOgnzwqtG197hftvZOfK_LDqMo9VI5iRnkX4f2K9Wno7tBzVTxrLi4Xs7doGsChAkL6ejRykvTtDMHMdNR-FlScXPT4wwNeD7Y-AZa1Rb5XVpDUsv2S2qXs3ZSWjxJg9uGiq1QYLG1FUfMVMVDQq8aoDWLjkUGk2CR0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22tradehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C2%7CL%2C2%7CM%2C0%7CN%2C0&tid=3&_=1363305928541
with no response

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: it's going inside the javascript handler
$.connection.hub.error(function () {

Comment: There's definitely some other issue going on here.  Is that first code sample the exact code sample that's being run?  What you're experiencing seems like an app trying to connect to a server that's cross domain.

Comment: well funny thing, I run on localhost in IE this morning it works. the other night it didn't, so could be that it had the JS file to connect to the production site? even if I use relative ...<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>